# Stop Ajax Request in UIWebView in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView control loading a URL that have AJAX on HTML. My concern is to stop AJAX request on the page. I can stop all further navigation by using delegate method as:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest: (NSURLRequest*)req navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
```

Or I can use the simple method `[webView stopLoading]`, but non of these able to stop internal AJAX request running on browser.

Please suggest if is there any way where we can stop AJAX

Answer (score 2):

Ajax URLs are not passed to shouldStartLoadWithRequest, only page and iframe loads. To capture any other sort of network traffic you can use NSURLCache which is basically a cache layer between UIWebView and network. It can also capture requests based on some rules you defined and return an error or empty response for it as if that error was in the cache.

Here is a sample to replace some url content:
http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/09/substituting-local-data-for-remote.html